# Get MIME type of File object

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I have a [dart:html `File`](https://api.dart.dev/dev/2.8.0-dev.7.0/dart-html/File-class.html) object and I want to determine the MIME type from the file contents rather than the extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [the mime package's](https://pub.dev/packages/mime) function [`lookupMimeType`](https://pub.dev/documentation/mime/latest/mime/lookupMimeType.html) and pass in the `headerBytes` by calling [`slice`](https://api.dart.dev/dev/2.8.0-dev.7.0/dart-html/Blob/slice.html) on the `File` with [`defaultMagicNumbersMaxLength`](https://pub.dev/documentation/mime/latest/mime/defaultMagicNumbersMaxLength.html)

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:mime/mime.dart' as mime;

Future<String?> getMimeType(File file) async {
  // Create a slice for the header.
  final slice = file.slice(0, mime.defaultMagicNumbersMaxLength);

  // Read the file header's contents.
  final fileReader = FileReader();
  fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(slice);
  await fileReader.onLoad.first;
  final header = fileReader.result as List<int>;

  // Empty string for the file name because it's not relevant.
  return mime.lookupMimeType('', headerBytes: header);
}
```